Apple Mail on iOS email with a gradient on tr displays incorrectly
I am working on a Laravel app and I am building some emails. I am trying to create table with tr elements which have a gradient background and it works correctly in Gmail and Apple Webmail. However, on iOS in Apple Mail it is as if I've added a separate gradient to each of the tr's children tds. Here are some screenshots of the correct way I need it in Gmail and how it is on iOS:
Gmail (ignore the fading text in the background that is a problem with my screenshot tool): 
iOS: 
Here is my CSS for the tr:
border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29); 
background: rgba(243,175,0,.2);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(223,167,20,0.3) 0.06%, rgba(223, 167, 20, 0.00) 31.41%, rgba(223, 167, 20, 0.00) 67.6%, rgba(223,167,20,0.3) 96.57%);
mix-blend-mode: multiply;

can't find any info on the subject in Google. According to caniemail gradients are supported on ios. Any ideas?
